# Problem in generated classes by xsd schema

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, jaxb

I have a xsd schema. I generated by Eclipse plugin java classes(Generate-->JaxbClasses). 
My generated classes show an error on xmlRootElement annotation:
@XmlRootElement(name = "CommonData"):

On this line, I receive this error

> "Cannot resolve XML element declaration with namespace '' and name 'CommonData' in this context".

The other generated classes have the same problem.

Any suggestion?

Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"      elementFormDefault="unqualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:simpleType name="MsisdnInterrogatoType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="20"/>
            <xs:pattern value="([0-9])+"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="OperatoreType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="12"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="SceltaTipoTrafficoType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="Y"/>
            <xs:enumeration value=" "/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="SubSysType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="10"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:element name="QueryRiepilogoCosti">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="CommonData"/>
                <xs:element ref="QueryGroup"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="CommonData">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="SubSys" type="SubSysType"/>
                <xs:element name="Operatore" type="OperatoreType"/>
                <xs:element name="MsisdnInterrogato" type="MsisdnInterrogatoType"/>
                <xs:element name="DataInizio" type="xs:dateTime"/>
                <xs:element name="DataFine" type="xs:dateTime"/>
                <xs:element name="TutteLeTipologie" type="SceltaTipoTrafficoType" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="QueryGroup">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="WAP" type="SceltaTipoTrafficoType"/>
                <xs:element name="GPRS" type="SceltaTipoTrafficoType"/>
                <xs:element name="GPRSEstero" type="SceltaTipoTrafficoType"/>
                <xs:element name="WAPEvento" type="SceltaTipoTrafficoType"/>
                <xs:element name="GPRSEvento" type="SceltaTipoTrafficoType"/>
                <xs:element name="WLAN" type="SceltaTipoTrafficoType" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="RCS" type="SceltaTipoTrafficoType"/>
                </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>'
```

Comment: What are you using?

Comment: @FRANCESCA add namespace into the xsd first. then regenerate the java classes

Comment: Thanks, I understood the problem is the namespace absent in the schema, but I don't understand how I should insert it. Could you explain me rules to do it please. Thank you very much.